# Get current image url - php

Tags: php, image, dynamic, src

I'd like to pass the current `img` `src` to a function I'm working on (to get more data from a database)

Is there a simple way to grab the `src` from within the `img` tag?

I'd like to do this:
`<img src="http://example.com/images/1.jpg" alt="amazing image" data="<?php echo( get_extra_data($img_src) ); ?>" />`

Rather than this:
`<img src="http://example.com/images/1.jpg" alt="amazing image" data="<?php echo( get_extra_data("http://example.com/images/1.jpg") ); ?>" />`

I'd like to dynamically get the `src` from the current `img` rather than having to have the url twice if that makes sense.

In other words, could the function `get_extra_data()` reference the `img` element it was called from?

This is because I'd like to just paste `data="<?php echo( get_extra_data($img_src) ); ?>"` into the exsisting image elements I need it on.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you will need to do that in javascript

Comment: Where did you get `get_extra_data()`?

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin Thats the name of the function I'm calling that will return some other data from the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, I hadn't considered that approach. I guess I could do a search into how I can pass a JavaScript variable to PHP...

Comment: That would be AJAX